# vqmod adding code twice in Opencart

Tags: php, opencart, vqmod

I am writing a short script to add to `catalog/model/checkout/order.php` using vqmod in Opencart. However it seems to add the code twice. Its worth mentioning it also seems to create two files

```
vq2-catalog_model_checkout_order.php
```

and

```
vq2-vqmod_vqcache_vq2-catalog_model_checkout_order.php
```

Its in this second file that the code is repeating itself.

```
<modification>
    <id>MyMod</id>
    <version>203.1</version>
    <vqmver>2.5.1</vqmver>
    <author>My Company</author>
    <email>a@example.com</email>
    <website>http://www.example.com/</website>
    <file name="catalog/model/checkout/order.php"  error="skip">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[
                $text .= $language->get('text_new_footer') . "\n\n";
                ]]></search>
            <add trim="true"><![CDATA[
                    // add code here
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```

outcome in the second file `vq2-vqmod_vqcache_vq2-catalog_model_checkout_order.php`:

```
$text .= $language->get('text_new_footer') . "\n\n";
// add code here
// add code here
```

Comment: Maybe there is another **vQmod** that adds code?

Comment: Nope, I even did a grep for "catalog/model/checkout/order.php" in the vqmod folder and it only showed up in that one file

Comment: I also searched in the entire site for that partcular code and its only showing up in the vqmod folder

Comment: search the keyword in vqmod folder instead...

Comment: do mean `$text .= $language->get('text_new_footer') . "\n\n";` in this case? I did there and it is only showing up in the generated files and the one xml file where I have it set. Strange one

Comment: this might be caused by a conflict between ocmod and vqmod.  try refreshing your ocmod cache and then clearing vqcache files.